# Is there a good CLI tool for developing, scaffolding and maintaining React applications?

Tags: reactjs, command-line-interface, angular-cli, code-generation

[Create React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) seems to be the go-to choice for quickly getting a new, green-field React application off the ground.

However, I would like to see a React CLI tool that can help the developer to develop on top of that foundation.

For example, quickly generating new components or automating complex code manipulations using something like [Schematics](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2).

Basically I'm looking for a React equivalent of the [Angular CLI](https://angular.io/cli).

Does such a thing exist? If not, why not? Would it be a good candidate for a new open-source initiative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered a project called [hygen](http://www.hygen.io/) that fits the bill.

It features a pretty light-weight CLI that can scaffold React components, but also allows some extensibility/flexibility through its [template](http://www.hygen.io/templates) mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Telosys** http://www.telosys.org/

It's a lightweight code generator (free and Open Source). Telosys is often used to bootstrap a project. It provides scaffolding capabilities that can be used to accelerate the development of all the layers of the architecture.

The CLI tool ( http://www.telosys.org/cli.html ) seems well suited to your needs